# select options with background:inherit bug

Tags: html, css

While I was working on styling a page using background:inherit for some elements, I noticed that for some reason the options of a dropdown/select sometimes lost their background color (on Google Chrome). I did some testing, and found out it apparently has to do with if the select element itself has a parent or not.

You can see what I mean using this small example:

```html
<div style="background: blue; margin-bottom: 50px;">
 <select style="background: inherit;">
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="stitch">Option 1</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div style="background: blue; margin-bottom: 50px;">
 <div>
  <select style="background: inherit;">
   <option value="default">Default</option>
   <option value="stitch">Option 1</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

When you now click open both dropdowns, I would expect them both to have blue background colors. This are the results I got however (images combined for easier comparison)

[image: dropdowns have different colors]

I was wondering if this is the intended way for the inherit value to work, and why it works the way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit value here is the element's immediate parent property
Second dropdown div is not having any background color and the default white background is applied for the select.

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NBqeOg?editors=1010

I have created another div with different background and making select to inherit

```html
<div style="background: blue; margin-bottom: 50px;">
 <select style="background: inherit;">
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="stitch">Option 1</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div style="background: blue; margin-bottom: 50px;">
 <div>
  <select style="background: inherit;">
   <option value="default">Default</option>
   <option value="stitch">Option 1</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div style="background: blue; margin-bottom: 50px;">
 <div style="background: red;">
  <select style="background: inherit;">
   <option value="default">Default</option>
   <option value="stitch">Option 1</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, my misunderstanding was that I thought it would also inherit from grandparents if the css was never overwritten. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Div inherits property from it's parent!

```
<pre><div style="background: blue; margin-bottom: 50px;"><!-- select's parent -->
    <select style="background: inherit;">
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="stitch">Option 1</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style="background: blue; margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <div style="background: inherit;"><!-- select's parent -->
        <select style="background: inherit;">
            <option value="default">Default</option>
            <option value="stitch">Option 1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div></pre>
```